# I need to send my values using ajax twice first on page 1 then from that two page 2

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to send my values using ajax from original page to the page one and then to page 2 this is my code but it seems to be not working.

This is the code on the original page here I have only given the script as I am just using the click event of my div to send the values

```
<script>
    function displayRecords(numRecords, pageNum,x,catg) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "button.php",
            data: {
                show:numRecords,
                pagenum:pageNum,
                val12:x,
                catg12:catg,
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#tabs1-html").html(data);  
            }
        });
    }

    function changeDisplayRowCount(numRecords) {
        displayRecords(numRecords, 1);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tab12').click(function(){
        var catg=$('#cat').val();
        var x =$(this).val();

        displayRecords(5,1,x,catg);
        });
    });
</script>
```

now for the code on my page 1

here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_data(no,x,catg) {
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'question_call.php',
            data:{
                row_no:no,
                X:x,
                category:catg,                                
            },
            success:function(response) {
                document.getElementById("pagination_div").innerHTML=response;
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tota_page_div').click(function(){
          var catg = $category.val();
          var x    = $X.val();       
          get_data(no,x,catg);
        });
    });
</script>
```

and these are the values where i saved the previous ones

```
$X        = $_GET['val12'];
$category = $_GET['catg12'];
```

Now when I try to use print_r on my page 2 it only shows row_no not catg12 and val12

Comment: did you checked values are avalilable in function get_data() or not ???

Comment: the get_data is not getting any values to pass using the ajax